# Prolog - Formatting crossword

Tags: formatting, prolog, crossword

I've written a predicate called solve_crossword that looks like this:

```
solve_crossword(X,C):-
C= [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,
    B1,' ',B3, ' ', B5,
    C1, C2,C3,C4,C5,
    D1,' ',D3,' ', D5,
    E1,E2,E3,E4,E5],
member([A1, A2, A3, A4, A5], X),
member([C1, C2, C3, C4, C5], X),
member([E1, E2, E3, E4, E5], X),
member([A1, B1, C1, D1, E1], X),
member([A3, B3, C3, D3, E3], X),
member([A5, B5, C5, D5, E5], X).
```

Now, I want to write a predicate called write_crossword that formats the crossword. If I have a list of words I want it to look like this:

```
| ?- words(X), solve_crossword(X, C), write_crossword(C).

DITCH
O U O
DITTO
G O E
EARLY

C = [[68,73,84,67,72],[79,32,85,32,79],...
X = [[68,73,83,84,82],[68,73,84,67,72],...
```

With

```
words([
       "DISTR",
       "DITCH",
       "DITTO",
       "DITTY",
       "DODGE",
       "EARED",
       "EARLY",
       "EARTH",
       "EASEL",
       "HONOR",
       "HOOEY",
       "HORDE",
       "TUQUE",
       "TURPS",
       "TUTOR",
       "TWAIN"
       ]).
```

Rows 1, 3, 5 and columns 1, 3, 5 are supposed to be words.

Comment: you can now, I merged your accounts

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (note I corrected your code for solve_crossword):

```
solve_crossword(X,C):-
  C= [[A1,A2,A3,A4,A5],
      [B1,Space,B3, Space,B5],
      [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5],
      [D1,Space,D3,Space,D5],
      [E1,E2,E3,E4,E5]],
  atom_codes(' ', [Space]),
  member([A1, A2, A3, A4, A5], X),
  member([C1, C2, C3, C4, C5], X),
  member([E1, E2, E3, E4, E5], X),
  member([A1, B1, C1, D1, E1], X),
  member([A3, B3, C3, D3, E3], X),
  member([A5, B5, C5, D5, E5], X).

write_crossword([]).
write_crossword([Line|Lines]):-
  atom_codes(SLine, Line),
  write(SLine),
  nl,
  write_crossword(Lines).
```

atom_codes/2 converts between an atom and a list of character codes.